# Show all elements in a protocol buffer message

Tags: c#, reflection, protocol-buffers

How can I show all elements in a protocol buffer message?
Do I need to use reflection or convert the message into an XML message and then show it?
Ideally some generic code that will work for any message.
Lars

Answer (score 1):

A protobuf message is internally ambiguous unless you have the .proto schema (or can *infer* a schema) available, as (for example) a "string" wire-type could represent:

- a utf-8 string
- a BLOB
- a sub-message
- a packed array

Similar ambiguity exists for all wire-types (except perhaps "groups").

My recommendation would be to run it through your existing deserialization process (against the type-model that you presumably have available in the project) to get an object model suitable for inspection. From the object-model you have all the usual options - reflection, serialization via `XmlSerializer` / `JavaScriptSerializer`, etc.

If all you have is the raw data, there is a wireshark plugin that might help, or protobuf-net exists a ProtoReader class that might be useful for parsing such a stream; but the emphasis here is that the stream is tricky to decipher in isolation.

Comment: I do have the .proto file, does that help?

Comment: @user294569 then the simplest way is *still* to deserialize it into your object model :)