# How can I format a Google Protocol Buffers object in XML and parse from XML

Tags: c++, xml, protocol-buffers

I'm going to pass GPB objects over the wire but in the local application I need to save them locally in XML (customer demands XML, no editing tool, don't ask me why) so the customer can edit the XML (which brings me to the other part of my question - parsing GPB from XML).
Is anyone aware of a framework which does this?
I need this code in C++ on Windows.

Comment: I don't know about Google Protocol Buffers, but you could start with TinyXML for your XML parsing if you want. Or PugiXML. Both are pretty decent.

Comment: The Piqi project has a command-line tool for converting between Protobuf/XML/JSON: http://piqi.org Although it is not exactly what you are looking for, it is a very stable and compact type-based validating format converter. (I'm the author; let me know if you have any questions).

Answer (score 2):

There is no C++ implementaion for this as far as I am aware. 
You can port this code from Java http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/
if you want we can port it togeather I also need the same as you!

One of the problems is that pb are not self describing so you need to whole the schema outside  which is not ideal.

The documentaion on reflections which onbody uses inside of Google is a little confusing for me. http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message.html#Message.

Also see here [Show all elements in a protocol buffer message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372604/show-all-elements-in-a-protocol-buffer-message)